# How to get the private helper section Xcode

Tags: javascript, swift, xcode

I can't seem to get the `private helper` divider to appear on the `drop-down` anyone know the issues ? I am using Xcode 9.2

```
private class func MaleHaircuts() -> ProductLine {
    // (1) MALE HAIRCUT, FEMALE HAIRCUT
    var products = [Product]()
    products.append(Product(titled: "Afro", description: "BLANK", imageName: "male afro"))
    products.append(Product(titled: "Bald", description: "BLANK", imageName: "bald"))
    products.append(Product(titled: "Hair Fade", description: "BLANK", imageName: "hair-fade"))
    return ProductLine(named: "MaleHaircuts", includeProducts: products)
}
```

View screen shot is below

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs to be formatted like this.

```
// MARK: - Private Helper Methods
```